# TextView Scroll Change Listener

Tags: java, android, scroll, textview, scrollview

There is a good thing in api 23 - TextView.setOnScrollChangeListener.
Does anyone know, is it real to make this listener for smaller api?
I know that i can use ScrollView, but I have some trouble with it and don't want to use it.
Thank you.